# android.view.InflateException Binary XML file line #11 Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, mysql, google-maps, android-fragments

Hello i have a problem with `google map v2`.

When i start the project i found this in log cat in this application i try to store user location in `mysql` database.

```
Target SDK : API 18: Android 4.3
Compile With: API 18: Android 4.3
```

Error Log :

```
05-07 14:35:30.947: W/dalvikvm(1206): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2a74ba8)
05-07 14:35:30.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1206): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-07 14:35:30.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1206): Process: in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkermysql, PID: 1206
05-07 14:35:30.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1206): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkermysql/in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkermysql.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
05-07 14:35:30.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
05-07 14:35:30.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
05-07 14:35:30.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-07 14:35:30.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
05-07 14:35:30.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-07 14:35:30.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-07 14:35:30.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-07 14:35:30.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-07 14:35:30.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-07 14:35:30.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-07 14:35:30.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-07 14:35:30.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-07 14:35:30.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1206): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
05-07 14:35:30.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
05-07 14:35:30.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
05-07 14:35:30.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
05-07 14:35:30.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
05-07 14:35:30.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
05-07 14:35:30.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
05-07 14:35:30.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
05-07 14:35:30.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkermysql.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
05-07 14:35:30.967: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
```

`MainActivity.java`

```
package in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkermysql;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Getting reference to SupportMapFragment
        SupportMapFragment fragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        // Creating GoogleMap from SupportMapFragment
        mGoogleMap = fragment.getMap();

        // Enabling MyLocation button for the Google Map
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // Setting OnClickEvent listener for the GoogleMap
        mGoogleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latlng) {
                addMarker(latlng);
                sendToServer(latlng);
            }
        });

        // Starting locations retrieve task
        new RetrieveTask().execute();

    }

    // Adding marker on the GoogleMaps
    private void addMarker(LatLng latlng) {
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latlng);
        markerOptions.title(latlng.latitude + "," + latlng.longitude);
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    }

    // Invoking background thread to store the touched location in Remove MySQL server
    private void sendToServer(LatLng latlng) {
        new SaveTask().execute(latlng);
    }


    // Background thread to save the location in remove MySQL server
    private class SaveTask extends AsyncTask<LatLng, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(LatLng... params) {
            String lat = Double.toString(params[0].latitude);
            String lng = Double.toString(params[0].longitude);
            String strUrl = "http://10.0.2.2/location_marker_mysql/save.php";                   
            URL url = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(strUrl);

                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(
                        connection.getOutputStream());

                outputStreamWriter.write("lat=" + lat + "&lng="+lng);               
                outputStreamWriter.flush();
                outputStreamWriter.close();

                InputStream iStream = connection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new
                InputStreamReader(iStream));

                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

                String line = "";

                while( (line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    sb.append(line);
                }

                reader.close();
                iStream.close();


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

    }

    // Background task to retrieve locations from remote mysql server
    private class RetrieveTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String strUrl = "http://10.0.2.2/location_marker_mysql/retrieve.php";               
            URL url = null;
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            try {
                url = new URL(strUrl);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                InputStream iStream = connection.getInputStream();              
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));         
                String line = "";               
                while( (line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    sb.append(line);
                }

                reader.close();
                iStream.close();                            

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }       
            return sb.toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {           
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            new ParserTask().execute(result);
        }

    }

    // Background thread to parse the JSON data retrieved from MySQL server
    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<HashMap<String, String>>>{
        @Override
        protected List<HashMap<String,String>> doInBackground(String... params) {
            MarkerJSONParser markerParser = new MarkerJSONParser();
            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                json = new JSONObject(params[0]);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            List<HashMap<String, String>> markersList = markerParser.parse(json);
            return markersList;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
            for(int i=0; i<result.size();i++){
                HashMap<String, String> marker = result.get(i);
                LatLng latlng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(marker.get("lat")), Double.parseDouble(marker.get("lng")));
                addMarker(latlng);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

`Android Mainfest`

```
<i>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkermysql"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <!-- Protect the map component of the application using application signature -->
    <permission 
        android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkermysql.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" 
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <!--  Allows to receive map -->
    <uses-permission android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkermysql.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <!-- Used by the Google Maps Android API V2 to download map tiles from Google Maps servers -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- Allows the Google Maps Android API V2 to cache map tile data in the device's external storage area -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Allows the Google Maps Android API V2 to use WiFi or mobile cell data (or both) to determine the device's location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- Allows the Google Maps Android API V2 to use the Global Positioning System (GPS) 
    to determine the device's location to within a very small area -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- Allows to contact Google Serves -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

     <!-- Google Maps Android API V2 requires OpenGL ES version 2 -->
    <uses-feature 
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />    

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkermysql.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>










        <!-- Specifies the Android API Key, which is obtained from Google API Console -->
        <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyARMaABMsbMqdHIwf1jysdyi9rFOsore6o" />      


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What is line 35 of MainActivity? Is that where you set your content view or try to initialize your map fragment?

Comment: You are missing `<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />` in your manifest..try adding it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing

```
<meta-data     
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"  
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Try adding this in your Manifest..

Also check whether you are using

```
class = "com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

for your fragment..

Answer (score 0):

fixed...add this permission to your manifest.xml

```
< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```